# How to get Cookie value Without page refresh in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am done login using Popup,After Checked username and password correct means to set the username,type and id in cookie , once page refresh only i get the Cookie value,I want to get the cookie value without page refresh.

My Code:

```
/*login*/
                function login(formStatus) {
                    if (formStatus.$valid) {
                        self.scope.userlogin.user_type = 1;
                        UserService.login(self.scope.userlogin, function(response) {
                            if (response.success) {
                                self.scope.error = null;
                                UserService.setCredentials(response.result.username, response.result.user_type, response.result.id);

                             }


                        });
                    }
                }
```

Service Code:

```
/**
 * Set cookie after login
 */
 this.setCredentials = function (username, type, id) {
    $rootScope.globals = {
        currentUser: {
            username: username,
            type: type,
            id:id
        }
    };

    $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
};
```

What's Wrong in My code? Once page Refresh only i got that COokie value.
Please give me Solution.

Comment: How are you checking the cookie value?

Comment: In Controller self.scope.userType =(angular.isDefined($rootScope.globals.currentUser))?$rootScope.globals.currentUser.type:""; check in view userType == 1 like these